# How to get around loss of precision when importing data to R?

Tags: java, r

I have a generated CSV file from my `Java` code and now want to work with it in `R`. Problem is, that there is a precision issue with one of my attributes.

The Timestamp attribute was saved as `long` in Java. When importing the data to R this

```
1481653606064
1481653606064
1481653606064
1481653606065
1481653606068
1481653606073
1481653606081
1481653606083
```

gets converted to this:

```
1,48165E+12
1,48165E+12
1,48165E+12
1,48165E+12
1,48165E+12
1,48165E+12
1,48165E+12
1,48165E+12
```

which is not useful at all.

I just started working with R, so I don't know how to get around this probably simple issue. And I hope you can help me with that.

If there's need for any clarification, please leave a comment.

Comment: Can you do `str(DF$Timestamp)` to check the class of variable `Timestamp` where `DF` is your input data.frame. Most likely scenario is that its a just visual effect and timestamp has been formatted in scientific notation. To suppress it you can try `options(scipen=999)` and read the csv again.

Comment: The display of data is not the same as the precision of the storage - `x <- 1481653606064; print(x); dput(x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
X = read.csv(text="1481653606064
1481653606064
1481653606064
1481653606065
1481653606068
1481653606073
1481653606081
1481653606083", header=FALSE)

X
            V1
1 1.481654e+12
2 1.481654e+12
3 1.481654e+12
4 1.481654e+12
5 1.481654e+12
6 1.481654e+12
7 1.481654e+12
8 1.481654e+12


options(digits=13)
X
             V1
1 1481653606064
2 1481653606064
3 1481653606064
4 1481653606065
5 1481653606068
6 1481653606073
7 1481653606081
8 1481653606083
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no loss of precision happening, you just need to print it with full precision. Integer values up to 2^53 are stored exactly in numeric data type, and 2^53 is 15 digits long ("9,007,199,254,740,992") while your numbers are only 12 digits long.

```
> x = 1481653606083
> x
[1] 1.481654e+12
> sprintf("%.f",x)
[1] "1481653606083"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [bit64](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bit64/bit64.pdf) package along with the fread function to load your data from csv with the [data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf) package.